# Creating a new line after every 8th comma using string.prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
  rl.on('line', (line) => {

        line= line.trimRight();
        line= line.trimLeft();
        line = line.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        line = line.replace(/ /g, ',');
        lines.push(line);
      }
    });
```

My code above parses a file using read line. Now I am having difficulty adding a new line after every 8'th comma. Any ideas? Right now the parsed text file is showing up like in one big line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll probably use string `replace` with the following regular expression:

```
var result = line.replace(/(?:[^,]+,){8}/g, '$&\n');
```

```js
var line = '110:,20000004,2,OBJECT,LOCAL,DEFAULT,8,DAC0_Cmd_Local,112:,20000006,2,OBJECT,LOCAL,DEFAULT,8,DAC1_Cmd_Local,';

console.log( line.replace(/(?:[^,]+,){8}/g, '$&\n') );
```

Comment: I still want the last comma to be there, so I do not want to replace it.

Comment: It works in your snippet, but doesn't work in my code? Could it be that notepad just doesn't open it properly?

Answer (score 1):

```
rl.on('line', (line) => {
          if (line.includes('OBJECT', 0) && !line.includes('__',0)  && !line.startsWith('_', 51)) {
            line= line.trimRight();
            line= line.trimLeft();
            line = line.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
            line = line.replace(/ /g, ',');
            lines.push(line);
          }
          var grouping=[];
        for(var i=0;lines.length;i++){
        if(i%8==0){
        grouping.push("</br>");
        }
        grouping.push(lines[i]);
        }
        return grouping;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a little complex in my way but the [VisioN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1249581/vision) answer is really astonishing and my favorite due to less line of code:

```js
var str = '110:,20000004,2,OBJECT,LOCAL,DEFAULT,8,DAC0_Cmd_Local,112:,20000006,2,OBJECT,LOCAL,DEFAULT,8,DAC1_Cmd_Local,';
var itemPerLine = 8;

var result = 
  str.split(',')
  .reduce(function(r, v, i) {
    if (!(i % itemPerLine)) 
      r.push([]);
    r[r.length - 1].push(v);
    return r;
  }, [])
  .map(v => v.join(','))
  .join('\n');

console.log(result);
```